# Resizing for iPhone 4 from an iPhone 5 without using autolayout or making a new xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, scaling

My app currently works for iphone5 and 6, 6+, but not iphone4 (not for iPad, but that's not necessary at the moment). I wrote it originally with the storyboard being the dimensions of the iphone 5 screen, so that's where the problem arises. All the collision, pixels,outlines, etc have been fitted for the 5. It scales correctly when going up to the 6, but when it goes down to the 4, about 20% of the right side gets cut off. I was told to use autolayout previously but that messes with the integrity of the collision, because it was made without using it (Will definitely be used for the next app). While it's a simple game, it still would take a while to redo it completely and i can't imagine it would be the same. Is there some sort of reliable code I can use as almost a "quick fix" so that is resizes correctly for the 4 with all the same relative dimensions?

I saw somewhere you could test for the bounds and then have the program scale the screen accordingly, is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

The best thing you could do right now is take the hit to convert your code so it does not use hard coded numbers.  You said you built it to work specifically on 4" devices which tells me that you did things like x = 160; instead of x = view.bounds.width/2.  You now need to go through your code and anywhere that you just use a hard coded number like 160, consider what the code is actually trying to do (160 vs center of screen).

You do not need to use auto layout to accomplish what you want on different screen sizes but you do need to get rid of most hard coded numbers you set.

Comment: Sounds like a solid idea and fix, although like you said I will be taking the hit. My concern is that it seems like i'd have to make a second storyboard and resize it in there. Unless I'm not understanding it correctly. I can imagine the collision working correctly, but wouldn't it still have the size issue where it doesn't show the most right 1/2 inch?

Comment: If you really refuse to use auto layout, you can reposition the views programmatically based on the superviews size.  You can do this when you load the view, before you show it to the user.